# notepad++ regular expression replace an inner sequence of matched text

Tags: regex, notepad++

How would i replace all ocurances of "cast(net_price as decimal(9,2))=xxx AND" with "ROUND(net_price,2)=xxx AND" whilst maintaining xxx in Notepad++?  The statements are nested with other AND statements as below:

What are the required find and replace parameters for notepad++?

Example text:

```
OR (cast(net_price as decimal(9,2))=@var2 AND cost=@var3 AND blah)
```

Example result:

```
OR (ROUND(net_price,2)=@var2 AND cost=@var3 AND blah)
```

Every time i try to write my own regex it seems to select the entire line from net_price up to the last AND , i want it to select up to the first AND after net_price, then continue on to the next one.

I had thought that `net_price.*AND` would match net_price then anything until it found AND.  Plainly i am wrong and if someone could explain why i would appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you mention .NET? Notepad++ regex engine is Boost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `cast\((net_price) as decimal\(9,2\)\)(?==@var2 AND)`
- Replace with: `ROUND\($1,2\)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
cast\(                  # literally
(net_price)             # group 1, "net_price"
as decimal\(9,2\)\)     # literally
(?==@var2 AND)          # positive lookahead, make sure we have "=@var2 AND" after
```

**Replacement:**

```
ROUND\($1,2\)
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: @davec: OK, but it seemed clear to me, according to your question, that is what you want. You should edit your question and add more test cases, with example that must be changed and some other.

Comment: You are 100% correct toto. I apologise i had simplified the example too much!  I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Tote I am accepting your answer :) you have definitely answered answered the question as asked.  Sorry i worded it really badly.  It came about from a very large test script that casts to 10,2 10,4 and float all over the darn place.  When really it should just round it by 2 decimal places.  Thanks again, sorry for the confusion.  I will leave my answer too as it expands on the original and answers both questions, might help some other soul.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the oversimplified question i have edited it to reflect the true more complicated question.  Posting the answer in the hopes of giving back.

I should have pointed out that the sample data can be decimal(9,2) or float, or even decimal(9,4).  so its much more complicated than just a search and replace.  Sorry in trying to simplify for posting i oversimplified!!

It turned out that the correct reg is not .* as this is greedy match, I needed to use the .*? to match up to only the first AND statement after the net_price.  As a greedy match will match to the last pattern it can find and then look backward to match the last AND. which would select far too much of the line - which is what my problem was.

So the regex becomes: `cast\((net_price).*?\=(.*?) AND`
which:

```
finds cast( 
finds net_price and puts it into capture group 1
non greedy scans until it finds an equals character
captures non greedily the value into group 2
finds the AND
```

which captures into 2 groups net_price always in group 1 and the variable/quantity always in the group 2, everything else gets rewritten:

The replace becomes: `ROUND\($1,2\)=$2 AND`

Which replaces $1  (capture group 1) with net_price and $2 (capture group 2) with the value.

notepad++ search and replace window:
[image: notepad++ search and replace window:]